# c# List<KeyValuePair> Get Value by Key Or Index

Tags: c#, linq, keyvaluepair

How to get **value** by **key** for keyKeyValuePair

I have a  `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

```
var dataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

// Adding data to the list
dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("name", "foo"));
dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("name", "bar"));
dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("age", "24"));
```

Creating a loop for that list :

```
foreach (var item in dataList) {
    string key = item.Key;
    string value = item.Value;
}
```

What i'm trying to do is to get `string name = item["name"].Value` in some way like this :

```
foreach (var item in dataList) {
    // Print the value of the key "name" only
    Console.WriteLine(item["name"].Value);

    // Print the value of the key "age" only
    Console.WriteLine(item["age"].Value);
}
```

Or maybe get the **Value** by **Index** like `Console.WriteLine(item[0].Value)`

How could i achieve this?

**Note :** *i need to use only one foreach not to use separated foreach for every key.*

**Edit 1** if i used `if(item.Key == "name") { // do stuff }` i won't be able to use the other keys in that if statment, so i need to work in this logic :

```
if(item.Key == "name") {
    // Print out another key
    Console.WriteLine(item["age"].Value)

    // and that will not work because the if statment forced to be the key "name" only
}
```

**Edit 2** i've tried to use **Dictionary** and adding data to it like :

```
dataList.Add("name", "john");
dataList.Add("name", "doe");
dataList.Add("age", "24");
```

and it says `An item with the same key has already been added.` and i think because i'm adding multiple items with the same key `"name"` and i need to do that.

**Edit 3** What i'm trying to achieve `instead of how i try to do it` :

I'm trying to loop through the **List** and making a condition if item with key **path** file exists or not like this :

```
if(File.Exists(item["path"]) { Console.WriteLine(item["name"]) }

// More Explained

foreach (var item in dataList) {
    if (File.Exists(//the key path here//)) {
        MessageBox.Show("File //The key name here// exists.");
    }else {
        MessageBox.Show("File //The key name here// was not found.");
    }
}
```

and the issue that i can't use item["path"] that way .. all i can do is item.Key & item.Value

Comment: Is there a reason you have a `List` instead of just a `Dictionary<string, string>`? Your use case of searching by key makes it look like you don't actually need the list.

Comment: can you have an example of using `Dictionary<string, string>` because i have tried to use it but it said there are more items with the same key? i want to have multiple items with the same key. if that is possible, my issue will be solved.

Comment: At this point, this really seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you take a step back, and explain exactly *what you're trying to do* **instead of** *how you're trying to do it*?

Comment: i've updated the question can you read the **Edit 3** Part, please?

Comment: Are the key names flexible or fixed?

Comment: The Keys are fixed but the Values are flexible.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you're doing it the wrong way. A List of `KeyValuePair` doesn't have any relations between its items. What you can do is create a class and add all the properties you want to it (Path, Name, etc.) and then you can create a list of that class. Another thing you can do *if it's only about paths and filenames* is to use the [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of creating your own.

Comment: Create a class with name, age and path properties, and then create a generic List of this class. I wish I could have given you a sample. But this thread has been closed, anyway.

Comment: I believe this question is not a duplicate because the other question doesn't provide answers related to my issue. anyway thank you guys for the help.

Comment: It was marked as duplicate because you misrepresented your question (i.e., the XY problem). At this point, I don't think editing the question would help. Also, I believe that using the `FileInfo` class or creating your own *(depending on what properties you need)* should be enough. If you still can't figure it out, you can ask another question and explain your actual requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the `foreach` query by the desired keys only:

```
foreach ( var item in dataList.Where( i => i.Key == "name" ) )
{
    //use name items
}
```

This uses LINQ to include only the `KeyValuePairs` where `Key` is `"name"`. You will have to add `using System.Linq` to the top of your source code file for this to work properly.

Comment: I have added a note in the question, please read it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to use just a single `foreach`, then each time you will get just one item, so you could just do something like `if ( item.Key == "name" ) ... else ...`?

Comment: `if(item.Key == "name") { Console.WriteLine(another key) }`
if i forced it to key "name" .. inslide that i can't get the other keys
i need to use multiple keys in the same `foreach` you get that?

Comment: The problem is there is no relation between "name" and "age". The `dataList` is just a list of values. First is a "name", second is a "name", third is "age". There is no "connection" between them. If you want to associate them somehow, you should create a custom class with `Name` and `Age` properties and then make a list of these.

Comment: Please read the **Edit 3** Part of the question.